# displaying HTML RSS feed using CEWP

Tags: css, rss, cewp

I'm trying to use a CEWP to display an RSS feed via an HTML page. When I link to the web page in the CEWP, the RSS feed displays perfectly in the web part. However, it seems as if the rest of my site is picking up the style sheet from the CEWP, and changing the style of all content on the page.

Any workaround for this issue?

Comment: why not use RSS feed webpart? you'd still have to override some css from controls.css or change the class name in the xsl.

Comment: Can you add the code of your CEWP in your question?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to display RSS feeds you have an out of the box RSS Feed web part and you customize the CSS for that.

**[How To: Customize the RSS feed web part](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb608445(v=office.14).aspx)**

For any business reasons if you still want to add from the CEWP then you have to make sure assign the classes to your HTML and apply styles to the HTML tags through CSS classes.

Example:

*HTML*

```
<div class="item-container">
   <p class="item-text">Hello World</p>
</div>
```

*CSS*

```
.item-container {
    font-size: 14px;
}

.item-container p { //.item-container .item.text
   font-weight:italic;
}
```